# prove that a space is not connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $S=\{(x,0)\} \cup\{(x,1/x):x>0\}$. Prove that $S$ is not a connected space (the topology on $S$ is the subspace topology)

My thoughts: Now in the first set $x$ is any real number, and I can't see that this set in open in $S$. I can't find a suitable intersection anyhow.

Comment: I would try to prove that both $\{(x,0)\}$ and $\{(1,1/x)\mid x > 0\}$ are clopens with this topology.

Comment: BTW, where you had {$(x,0)$}, I wrote $\{(x,0)\}$, with the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ _inside_ the math notation tags.  That is standard and avoids font mismatches and lack of standard spacing.  Just put backslashes on them, thus: \{(x,0)\} ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks matey. Been wondering that for a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $X = \{ (x, 0) : x \in \mathbb{R} \} \subset S$. Clearly $X$ is closed in $S$ since $X$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

But $X$ is also open in $S$, since $X= S \cap T$, where $T= \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y< \frac{1}{2x} , x>0\} \cup \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y < 1-x\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So $X$ is clopen, and $S$ is not connected.

Comment: Your second sentence isn't true. you haven't let $y=0$

Comment: Oh! Really sorry, I misrad the definition of $S$! I will edit.

Answer (score 3):

The set $\{(x,0) : x\in\mathbb R\}$ is open in $S$ because every point $(x,0)$ has an open neighborhood that does not intersect the graph of $y=1/x$.  Just use $I\times\{0\}$ where $I$ is any open interval containing $x$.

Then do a similar thing with the set $\{(x,1/x): x>0\}$.

Comment: I don't get why $I$ X {0} is an open set. How can you write is an intersection or union of sets of the form (a,b) X (c,d), which are the basis open sets of R^2?

Comment: How the heck is I x {0} open?

Comment: It is open because it is the intersection of an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ with this subspace. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi(x) = {1 \over 2x}$. Let $U = \{ (x,y) | x>0, \  y > \phi(x)\}$,
$V = \{ (x,y) | x>0, \  y < \phi(x)\}$. Then $U,V$ are disjoint, open, $S \cap U \neq \emptyset$, $S \cap V \neq \emptyset$ and $S \subset U \cup V$. Hence $S$ is not connected.